# Not able to install any software via apt-get install

Tags: ubuntu, installation, dpkg

I tried to install `flex` and `yacc` on my Ubuntu machine.

`sudo apt-get install byacc flex`

I get this error:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     flex : Depends: m4
            Depends: libfl-dev (= 2.5.35-10ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
     virtualbox-4.2:i386 : Depends: libpython2.7:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.7.4) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: psmisc:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: dkms:i386 but it is not installable
                           Recommends: linux-headers:i386
                           Recommends: gcc:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: make:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: binutils:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: pdf-viewer:i386
                           Recommends: python-central:i386 but it is not installable
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Why am I not able to install any software packages using `apt-get` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a problem with broken dependencies in your system, perhaps due a previous interrupted installation (virtualbox-4.2:i386?). In the output you have a possible solution:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It is the logical and safest first step, this will try to solve the problem. If the problem continues I'd try to remove the **virtualbox-4.2** package.

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-4.2
```

Comment: I did that way `sudo apt-get -f install` but it does crashed my Ubuntu. I just now recovered from it.

Comment: Have your mixed packages from non-official or from different ubuntu version repositories?

Comment: Can't get what your saying..

Comment: It is possible to define different repositories for apt editing the configuration file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Mixing repositories of different ubuntu versions you could create broken dependencies.

Comment: I remember hitting a very very very similar issue in my early Linux days (Also Ubuntu).  I don't even know HOW I got into that situation.  I just know I was getting the exact same errors and after 2 days of screwing with it, I backed up what I needed (which was not much at that point) and reinstalled.  I even had a few guys I work with that knew more about Linux look and they couldn't figure out what I'd done, either.  I've never had it happen again.  My point is, which path is going to be the smaller headache?  Spending hours, if not days, on this or spending an hour and reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: May be reinstall would be faster but what if you have the same problem in a couple of months? In my oppinion, reinstall must be the last thing to do. I agree, however, with backed up all the important data and only then try to solve the issue: I'd try to remove all the problematic packages and then reinstall just what I really need.

Comment: I tried to install virtual box with dpkg it got stopped in the middle of the process. Thats what now creating the problem@

Comment: @user150563 Then `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-4.2` or `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-4.2` should fix it.